# iOS 1004 Could not connect to the server

Tags: ios

I get a network problem. It shows `code -1004 message:Could not connect to the server`.It works right on 4G, but there is a bug in wifi: it shows the error. Sometimes, it works well, but sometimes it doesn't work.

I use android with same host address. On 4G and wifi, it all works right.
I have no ideas. What's wrong.

Comment: Please check for ATS in your plist for HTTP calls. Also, try to run the app in the mobile device not in Simulator.

Comment: ths.ATS i use this:NSAllowsArbitraryLoads true.my host address is http.
I use mobie not simulator

Answer (score 0):

We run into the same problem in recent project during test, now I know the reason is we are using a limited Wi-Fi, the router has some Qos rule, some tcp connections are randomly abandoned by the router, error - 1004 occurs, sad! Hope this info helps.